# Using Jquery to hide <p> based on its contents

Tags: jquery

Im trying to achieve the following:

A certain page will have a series of strings, which are replaced with database content if it exists.
For example:

```
<h2 class="label">Title:</h2>
<p class="value">{{Title}}</p>
```

Would become:

```
<h2 class="label">Title:</h2>
<p class="value">This is the title</p>
```

The problem is, if the database row for {{Title}} has never been entered, it displays the {{Title}} instead of replacing it with whitespace. So what id like to do is, with jquery, if .value contains {{, hide the whole element, in the same way display:none would.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.
Rob

Comment: Are you in control of the server-side? Sounds like the server-side logic just needs to be updated.

Comment: +1 with meder. If you do this with jQuery it will be visible for an instant. Better not showing it in first place using server-side processing.

Comment: The server side is a in house developed php CMS, unfortunately I'm not experienced enough in php (nor is time at an advantage at the moment) to tackle it there, although I do agree its how it _should_ be resolved. I managed to fix another similar issue with jquery with the help of stackoverflow members a few months ago and although its a bit of a botch, it keeps the users happy while we figure out a long term solution, like moving the content over to a backend that we can actually manage :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(function () // when DOM is ready for manipulation, do:
{
    // for each of the p-elements in the DOM (add your own context or class-scope
    // or whatever you can do to narrow down the list of elements here):
    $("p").each(function () 
    {
        // cache the element (always a good idea when doing multiple operations
        // on the same entity):
        var that = $(this);

        // if the text of the element is "{{Title}}" then hide the element:
        if (that.text() == "{{Title}}") that.hide();

        // alternatively you can do:

        // if the the characters "{{" exists at any position in the text of the
        // element, hide it:
        if (that.text().indexOf("{{") > -1) that.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: You are welcome. My code looks a bit bulky, but you have to remember that JavaScript is a horribly slow language, where you really have to optimize for speed. Take [Kobi]'s answer--it is _a lot_ cleaner than mine, but I suspect that it is also a lot slower on large collections.

Comment: Kobi has run some tests, and his code is about 2 times faster than mine. Even though my answer solved your problem, I suggest you accept his answer over mine, since its a lot slicker :)

Comment: @roosteronacid - I appreciate the juster, though it is unnecessary. Thanks.

Comment: Not at all, Kobi. This is about figuring out the best answer to a problem. And yours _is_ the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("p.value:contains('{{')").hide();
```

Edit:
There's a claim this code is slower. It should be said this is fairly basic, and in fact runs about **3 times faster**.
Check this example (first one is slower): http://jsbin.com/ikite

Comment: Nice one. I'm curious though.. what is the performance-hit? It's not the most basic selector :)

Comment: @roosteronacid - I'd say it's pretty basic, I've done more complex selectors and had no problems.

Comment: @anonymous downvoder - please explain. The code works, btw: http://jsbin.com/oquto

Comment: I'm the one down voting. The selector is very clean and easily readable. But if you we're to run it on a collection of, say, a 100 elements, you would experience rendering-blips.

Comment: You also have to consider other jQuery code running before/after your code.

Comment: That's ridiculous. You're suggesting using only a subset of jQuery.

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm suggesting. But I'll run some tests--It might just be that Sizzle translates your query into something along the lines of my logic. In which case I'd recommend your selector over my somewhat bulky code.

Comment: Well, it's a shame you don't trust jQuery enough to use it properly. Please, make your experiments and hopefully you'll learn something. You'll find out reinventing the wheel, as they say, is never a good idea

Comment: Could you try and use just one of the if-clauses?

Comment: Good point. That makes it just twice slower :) Btw, you can try it yourself at http://jsbin.com/ikite/edit

Comment: I stand corrected. Although my code runs a bit faster without the 2nd if-clause, your code is still about 2 times faster.

Comment: @roosteronacid - it's over. We're cool, time to move to the next question. Good night!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('p.value').each(function(i,e){
  if ($(e).text().match(/^{{.*}}$/)) {
    $(e).hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for... a pitty I suck at regular expressions

Comment: -1 I see no need to new up a RegExp object each p-element. You can do this with a simple indexOf or equality-operation.

Comment: Also, you are not caching anything--if we're talking a large collection of elements, wrapping "this" (or in your case "e") multiple times is quite the performance-hit.

Comment: I second those, wasn't really optimized for performance. I'd go for the simpler indexOf if you don't need to be more valid.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just give the p a class of title?

```
<h2 class="title label">Title:</h2>
<p class="title value"></p>
```

And then to hide / show it:

```
if(title != '')
{
    $('p.title.value').text(title);
}
else
{
    $('.title').hide();
}
```