# Remove elements with only a &nbsp; space using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to remove this

```
<p> </p>
```

using jQuery?

Comment: Question: do you control the generated source? If so, have you considered not generating empty tags?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Try:

```
$('p')
    .filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === '' && $(this).children().length == 0
    })
    .remove()
```

What that does is it finds all the `<p>`s that have nothing in them, and removes them from the DOM.

Comment: nice filter.  This will remove all empty <p> tags

Comment: Be warned this will also remove <p><img src="..."></p>

Comment: Although this is a good start, I've downvoted this answer for the reason given above by Greg.

Comment: @Greg `return $.trim($(this).text()) === '' && $(this).children().length == 0` will work then.

Comment: I've included a solution below that is generic and slightly faster than using $(this).children().length.

Answer (score 15):

As Greg mentions above, testing the trimmed .text() will remove paragraphs w/ no text, but do have a self-contained element like the `<img>` tag. To avoid, trim the .html() return. As text is considered a child element in the DOM, you'll be set.

```
$("p").filter( function() {
    return $.trim($(this).html()) == '';
}).remove()
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be a better solution for CMSs. Some rich text editors add `&nbsp;` inside empty paragraphs.

```
    $("p").filter( function() {

        var html = $(this).html();

        if(html == '' || html == '&nbsp;')
            return true;

    }).addClass('emptyP');
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably same answer as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519023/using-jquery-to-hide-p-based-on-its-contents), try to do this on code behind.

With jquery i'll use this:

```
$("p:empty").remove();
```

Also you could use .empty(), that will remove all child nodes from the set of matched elements.

Comment: This won't remove `<p> </p>` as that does not match the `:empty` selector.

Comment: In this case you can go just via css with: `p:empty { display: none; }`

Answer (score 1):

```
$("p").filter( function() {
            return $.trim($(this).html()) == '';
        }).remove()
```

I used this to remove empty paragraph that contains not element such as IMG, Input, Select, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to simply remove all empty P elements, or P's with only a single space, then you could do this:

```
$('p').map( function(){
  var html = $(this).html();
  if( !html.length || html == ' ' || html == String.fromCharCode(255) )
    return this;
}).remove();
```

This iterates through all of the P's on your page and if they match a certain criteria (they are empty or only have a whitespace) then it removes them from the DOM.

Also, by assigning our html content once to a local variable, it helps the script run faster. To look for non-breaking spaces I simply compare the contents to a string created from ASCII character code 255 (which is a non-breaking space).

jQuery's map() function can be great when a simple filter, or attribute comparison will not suffice.

You can read more about it here.... http://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score -1):

This should handle any element with ***no children of any type*** (including unwrapped text nodes).

```
$("p").filter(function() { 
  return !this.childNodes[0]
}).remove();
```

Comment: This won't remove `<p> </p>`, not sure if that was your intent.

Comment: Ouch. It does everything but answer the OP's question. That was definitely not my intent. Please downvote me.

Answer (score -4):

give it an id (to get the selector).

```
<p id="myP"></p>


<script>

$("#myP").remove();

</script>
```