# Check div.html() length after removing all empty p's <p></p>

Tags: jquery

I need to know what the length of div.html() would be after removing all the empty p's inside of it

Comment: What's the goal? You may want to just check: `div.text().length` without removing empty `<p>`s.

Comment: I vote this most confusing question ever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var div = $('div'),
    dHtml = div.html(),
    dHtml = dHtml.replace(/<p.*?>\s*<\/p>/g,'');

console.log(dHtml.length);
```

EDIT: altered RegEx in case the p tag had an id, class, or something. (i.e. `<p class="foo"></p>`)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you need the number of elements within the  then you're probably looking for the `children()` method. It's pretty self-explanatory. We'll also use the (intuitively named) `remove()` method.

So,

// html

```
<div id="content">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <img />
    <blockquote></blockquote>
</div>
```

---

```
        // javascript 

(function($){
    var $children = $('#content').children();
    var len = $children.length - $children.remove().length; 
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do `div.html().length`

Removing empty p tags courtesy of: [Remove elements with only a &nbsp; space using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520981/remove-empty-elements-with-jquery)

```
$('#divid p').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === '';
    }).remove();
```

Here is a working example using the [filter method](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in jQuery:

http://jsfiddle.net/MhMJc/1/

Answer (score 0):

this should give the lenght after deleting

```
$('div').remove('p').length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to find the length the div's content after p's have been removed from inside it. You can do

```
$('div').children().length
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/Ad8nK/