# Remove empty <li> using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove Empty elements with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520981/remove-empty-elements-with-jquery)

I want to remove empty `<li>` using jQuery. I am trying to do this but my code is not working as per my requirements. My code is show below.

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#u li').each(function() {
        if($(this).html(' ')) {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="u">
    <li>hi</li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @swapnesh The id of the element is `u`, hence `#u`... `#ul` wouldn't match anything (you're thinking of `ul`, but that would match *every* ul element instead of that particular one).

Comment: @Juhana lol my bad really :( i missed that stuff :(

Answer (score 5):

You are setting the html of the `<li>` to one space character, not checking if it's empty. Instead, try this (trimming might be a good idea to catch spaces and newlines):

```
if(!$.trim($(this).html())) {
    $(this).remove();
}
```

Also, you could use jQuery's [`:empty`](http://jqapi.com/#p=empty-selector) selector (this checks all child nodes including text nodes):

```
$('#u li:empty').remove();
```

However, this does not match elements with "*invisible text nodes*", for example `<li> </li>` (one space) → [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeYMN/1/).

Answer (score 5):

It should be as simple as that:

```
$('#u li:empty').remove()
```

Comment: Note: This does not match elements that have a space, non-breaking space or other non-visible characters, because those `<li>` elements do have a child text node. See http://jsfiddle.net/zeYMN/

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#u li').each(function() {
            if($(this).html().length == 0)
            {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```