# JQuery: select paragraphs that only contain "&nbsp;"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove elements with only a &nbsp; space using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520981/remove-elements-with-only-a-nbsp-space-using-jquery)

Wordpress does this thing with adding `<p>&nbsp;</p>` when doing a line-break in the backend.

I wonder if it is possible to select those `p`'s somehow with jquery.

[image]

I guess `empty()` wouldn't work since it isn't really empty but contains a `&nbsp;`. But `contains()` wouldn't probably work either since a lot of other paragraphs also contain a space, right?

I only want to select those paragpahs that have only this " " inside.

**UPDATE**

I should have mentioned that I don't want to remove the `p`s but add a class to it.

Comment: do you have access to the theme files?

Comment: @xFortyFourx yeah! Just so you know. I don't want to remove this `p`'s but add a class to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to your `functions.php` file if you have access to the theme files.

```
function user_content_replace($content) {
    return str_replace('<p>&nbsp;</p>','<p class="example">&nbsp;</p>',$content);
}
add_filter('the_content','user_content_replace', 99);
```

I made it insert a class instead of removing.

Comment: upvoted this answer because it's Wordpress specific

Answer (score 5):

This would work to select the paragraphs in question:

```
$("p").filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).html()) == '&nbsp;';
});
```

Comment: This will select all paragraphs that have `&nbsp;` instead of those that contain *only* `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @Juhana: My bad, I managed to misread what the question asked. Edited to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("p").each(function(){
                if($(this).html()=="&nbsp;") {
                    alert($(this).attr('id'));
                }   
            });
        });
```

And the HTML I used was

```
<p id="test" class="les">&nbsp;</p>
<p class="les" id="test1">aaaa &nbsp;</p>
```

So it should alert only **p with id test**

Hope this helps