# How can I select an element that contains "&nbsp;" within its HTML?

Tags: jquery

For example, in this HTML:

```
<div class="el"> &nbsp ;&nbsp ;&nbsp ;&nbsp ;HasNbsp</div>
<div class="el">NoNbsp</div>
```

I would like to select the element that has "&nbsp" in it.

I tried this:

```
$("div.el").html().contains("&nbsp;")
```

But it's not working.

How can I correctly target the element that contains a non-breaking space?

Note: I need to keep the non-breaking space, so removing it isn't an option.

Comment: You mean you want to select elements whose html contains `"&nbsp;"` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery: select paragraphs that only contain "&nbsp;"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703924/jquery-select-paragraphs-that-only-contain-nbsp)

Comment: i updated my question. hope it will be clearer this time. this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: @xawi try this http://jsbin.com/caguna/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  var regEx = /&nbsp;/gm;
  var elements = $("div p").filter(function(index, ele) {
     if(regEx.test($(ele).html())) {
       return true;
    }
  });
 // elements will contains DOM elements which has &nbsp;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/caguna/1/edit?html,js,output)**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="result">
<p>&nbsp; This contains space</p>
<p>hi, this doesn't</p>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  var regEx = /&nbsp;/gm;
  var elements = $("div p").filter(function(index, ele) {
 if(regEx.test($(ele).html())) {
   console.log("matched");
   return true;
}
  });
  $(elements).each(function() {
$(this).css({background: "red"});
  })
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do not need to run jQuery again in test: `.filter(function (i, el) { return /&nbsp;/gm.test(el.innerHTML); })`

Answer (score 7):

Use `\u00a0` in your selector instead of `&nbsp;`

So in your case, you want this:

`$("div.el").html().contains("\u00a0")`

Here's a CodePen with some more example code:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QJpPJV

Comment: With `\u00a0` it can also be used as `$("div.el:contains('\u00a0')")`

Comment: This worked fine to me! (I am using Cypress.io)

Answer (score 0):

You want to filter your query:

```
$("div.el").filter(function(){
    return $(this).html().indexOf(" ") > -1;
});
```

This will return the elements for which the function evaluates to "true", so just have your function return true on elements that contain "&nbsp".