# How can I remove these specific tags "<div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>" found in my article using CSS if not using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

`<div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>` - These tags has been added to my code because of a wysiwyg editor that I can't tweak or change. How can I remove it ideally using CSS or if not jQuery as it messes my layout.

[image]

Here is the structure generated by the wysiwyg and I need to clean it up. I can't change the wysiwyg editor because there are already lots of articles written using that editor. Only solution I can think of right now is purely frontend. By the way the platform is Rails

Thanks!

Comment: Show your hml structure plz

Comment: Are you using WordPress or something else? We need to know why you can't tweak or change your text editor.

Comment: `$('div').remove()` will do it, but also remove any other `div` elements in the page. We need to see your HTML to give you a more specific answer. Better yet, remove them directly from the source of the page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I select an element that contains "&nbsp;" within its HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29275742/can-i-select-an-element-that-contains-nbsp-within-its-html)

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML
`<div class="tempDiv" style="display:none"></div>`

And then some jQuery:

```
var crappyString = "<div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>";
$(".tempDiv").html(crappyString);
var sanitisedString = $(".tempDiv").text();
```

---

Related to an issue I've encoutered in the past: [When jQuery parsing html - Chrome throwing net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32653124/when-jquery-parsing-html-chrome-throwing-neterr-file-not-found)

---

> can't tweak or change

Sometimes it helps when you can talk to other devs: [TinyMCE- Get plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288083/tinymce-get-plain-text)

Answer (score 0):

For SEO is better to get out wysiwyg and take by hand every article and clean it. I get same situation in Joomla, and I do same. Is hard to make a good css/js selector to clear just div, div > p, div + br with no text. The default wordpress editor make text more clean, try to see if is free on the market and add it on your app.